Commander.js-based CLI tool's subcommands do not work on Windows
Context
I am building a CLI tool called solo to automate some routine procedures at my work.  I chose commander.js on TypeScript and Node.js as the tech stack. The tool will eventually be cross-platform, but currently it's mostly Windows-centric, as it's still a prototype in early stage of development. Even though I am on Windows, I use it exclusively from Git Bash.
Objective
I want to group some of my commands into logical categories, so that I can call them like this:
solo monorepo <subcommand> [options]
solo git <subcommand> [options]
solo aws <subcommand> [options]
# etc

At the moment, I am struggling with a minimal implementation for a single subcommand.
Problem
The following code attempts to define demo command and inner subcommand that can be invoked via solo demo inner and help queried via solo help demo inner.
For some reason it does not work.
Code
index.ts
import chalk from 'chalk';
import { Command } from 'commander';
import { allCommands } from './commands';
import { CliCommandMetadata, createCommandExample, describeCliOption } from './commands/cli-option';

export function createCli(): Command {
  const program = new Command();

  program
    .name(`solo`)
    .description(`CLI tool for automating routine processes.`)
    .option(`--verbose`, `Provide verbose output.`)
    .version(`0.0.1`);

  const cmd = program
    .command('demo')
    .description('Demo command')
    .addHelpText('after', `DEMO CMD`);
    // .action(() => {
    //   console.log('demo cmd');
    // });

  const subCmd = cmd
    .command('inner')
    .description('Inner command')
    .addHelpText('after', `INNER CMD`)
    .action(() => {
      console.log('inner cmd');
    });

  return program;
}


//function registerCommand(programCommand: Command, commandMetadata: CliCommandMetadata) {
//  let command = programCommand
//    .command(commandMetadata.name)
//    .description(commandMetadata.description);
//
//  command = Object
//    .values(commandMetadata.options)
//    .reduce(
//      (command, option) => command.option(...describeCliOption(option)),
//      command,
//    );
//
//  command
//    .addHelpText('after', formatExample(createCommandExample(commandMetadata)))
//    .action((...args: [str: any, options: any]) => {
//      commandMetadata.impl.apply(null, args);
//    });
//
//  function formatExample(...lines: string[]): string {
//    return `
//Example:
//${lines.join('\n')}
//`;
//  }
//}

package.json
{
  "name": "solo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "CLI tool for automating routine processes.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "bin": {
    "solo": "./dist/index.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node index.ts",
    "start-alt": "node -r ts-node/register index.ts",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "build": "npx tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.7.5",
    "chalk": "^4.1.2",
    "cli-table3": "^0.6.5",
    "commander": "^12.1.0",
    "semver": "^7.6.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^22.5.0",
    "@types/semver": "^7.5.8"
  }
}

Demonstration of failing attempts to use
This is what I see when trying to call my subcommand or help for it.
No matter what I do, I either get help for the demo container-command or the demo command itself triggers.
$ solo demo inner

> solo@0.0.1 start
> ts-node index.ts demo

Usage: solo demo [options] [command]

Demo command

Options:
  -h, --help      display help for command

Commands:
  inner           Inner command
  help [command]  display help for command
DEMO CMD

$ solo demo help inner

> solo@0.0.1 start
> ts-node index.ts demo

Usage: solo demo [options] [command]

Demo command

Options:
  -h, --help      display help for command

Commands:
  inner           Inner command
  help [command]  display help for command
DEMO CMD

$ solo help

> solo@0.0.1 start
> ts-node index.ts help

Usage: solo [options] [command]

CLI tool for automating routine processes.

Options:
  --verbose                        Provide verbose output.
  -V, --version                    output the version number
  -h, --help                       display help for command

Commands:
  solo-check-health                Self-check the health of the CLI tool.
                                   Validates the presence and the correctness of the config.
  demo                             Demo command
  help [command]                   display help for command

$ solo help demo

> solo@0.0.1 start
> ts-node index.ts help

Usage: solo [options] [command]

CLI tool for automating routine processes.

Options:
  --verbose                        Provide verbose output.
  -V, --version                    output the version number
  -h, --help                       display help for command

Commands:
  solo-check-health                Self-check the health of the CLI tool.
                                   Validates the presence and the correctness of the config.
  demo                             Demo command
  help [command]                   display help for command

$ solo demo help

> solo@0.0.1 start
> ts-node index.ts demo

Usage: solo demo [options] [command]

Demo command

Options:
  -h, --help      display help for command

Commands:
  inner           Inner command
  help [command]  display help for command
DEMO CMD

$ solo demo inner help

> solo@0.0.1 start
> ts-node index.ts demo

Usage: solo demo [options] [command]

Demo command

Options:
  -h, --help      display help for command

Commands:
  inner           Inner command
  help [command]  display help for command
DEMO CMD


I tried reproducing (on Mac) and had no problems when calling the code directly, like npx ts-node index.ts demo inner.

How do you have the solo command defined? (It looks like it might be triggering an npm run script that calls ts-node.)

@shadowspawn Please, see package.json in the updated question.  The fact it works on Mac, is the reason why I think it's a Windows-specific issue. I saw some github issues that talk exactly about that but can't find them anymore.

Your command-line examples show solo as the command but include ts-node index.ts in the output. ts-node only occurs in your example package.json in the "start" script, so I don't think your description of the observed behaviour matches what you currently show here.

Not exactly. There is a missing part. I have installed my script globally via npm install -g . So I am actually calling it via solo directly (without npm start at all)

That does not explain my observation that ts-node index.ts is appearing in the output of your command-line examples. That does not match the setup you have described, so I can't guess what parameters are actually being passed into your program. A simple check you can make is logging out process.argv in your program to see if the expected command-line arguments are actually making it to your program, or if the problem lies outside the program code as such.
